# Font style in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that will change paragraph style, color and size and I want it to make those 3 things but I don't know how.

- color is assigned to button
- style is assigned to select with 2 options
- size is changed according input type=number value in percentages

For now it just ignores if and changes font to red and italic

```js
function red() {
  if (document.getElementById('style').value == 'style-1') {
    document.getElementById('result').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('result').style.fontStyle = 'normal';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('result').style.fontStyle = 'italic';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Text size</p>
<input type='number' id='size' class='input-width'>%
<p>
  <select id='style' size='2'>
    <option id='style-1'>normal</option>
    <option id='style-2'>italic</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>What color?</p>
<input type='button' value='' class='button-red' onclick='red()'>
<input type='button' value='' class='button-green' onclick='green()'>
<input type='button' value='' class='button-blue' onclick='blue()'>
<p id='result'>This is an example</p>
```

Comment: Does this help you for example?
document.getElementById("result").style.fontSize = "x-large";

Comment: Not entirely sure what the question is!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for a generic solution like this? Here I have added a `setColor` method on the button click, that function will take the `font-size`, `font-style`, and `color` accordingly.

```js
function setColor(color) {
  const style = document.getElementById("style").value;
  const fontSize = document.getElementById("size").value;
  document.getElementById("result").style.color = color;
  document.getElementById("result").style.fontSize = fontSize + '%';
  document.getElementById("result").style.fontStyle = style;
}
```

```html
<p>Text size</p>
<input type="number" id="size" class="input-width" />%
<p>
  <select id="style" size="2">
    <option id="style-1">normal</option>
    <option id="style-2">italic</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>What color?</p>
<input type="button" value="red" class="button-red" onclick="setColor('red')" />
<input type="button" value="green" class="button-green" onclick="setColor('green')" />
<input type="button" value="blue" class="button-blue" onclick="setColor('blue')" />

<p id="result">This is an example</p>
```

*Edit:*
If you are looking for updating the styles on the changing the input, you can follow one of this methods.

1. Give an `on-change` function to the input elements and `on-click` to the buttons.
2. Bind `on-change` and `on-click` events through javascript.

I have added both the implementations here.

*Scenario 1*

Giving `on-change` function to the input elements and `on-click` to the buttons.

```js
function setColor(e) {
    switch (e.target.type) {
        case "number":
            // This node is font size input
            const fontSize = e.target.value;
            document.getElementById("result").style.fontSize = fontSize + "%";
            break;
        case "select-one":
            // This node is font style select
            const style = e.target.value;
            document.getElementById("result").style.fontStyle = style;
            break;
        case "button":
            // If the type is button, this is font color buttons
            const color = e.target.value;
            document.getElementById("result").style.color = color;
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Text size</p>
<input type="number" id="size" onchange="setColor(event)" class="input-width" />%
<p>
  <select id="style" size="2"  onchange="setColor(event)">
    <option id="style-1">normal</option>
    <option id="style-2">italic</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>What color?</p>
<input type="button" value="red" class="button-red" onclick="setColor(event)" />
<input type="button" value="green" class="button-green" onclick="setColor(event)" />
<input type="button" value="blue" class="button-blue" onclick="setColor(event)" />

<p id="result">This is an example</p>
```

*Scenario 2*

Binding `on-change` and `on-click` events through javascript.

Here I have selected the `input` `select` and buttons by using `document.querySelectorAll` and added the events from javascript method.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='number'], select");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']");
inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
        setColor(event);
    });
});
buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        setColor(event);
    });
});
function setColor(e) {
    switch (e.target.type) {
        case "number":
            // This node is font size input
            const fontSize = e.target.value;
            document.getElementById("result").style.fontSize = fontSize + "%";
            break;
        case "select-one":
            // This node is font style select
            const style = e.target.value;
            document.getElementById("result").style.fontStyle = style;
            break;
        case "button":
            // If the type is button, this is font color buttons
            const color = e.target.value;
            document.getElementById("result").style.color = color;
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Text size</p>
<input type="number" id="size" class="input-width" />%
<p>
    <select id="style" size="2">
    <option id="style-1">normal</option>
    <option id="style-2">italic</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>What color?</p>
<input type="button" value="red" class="button-red" />
<input type="button" value="green" class="button-green" />
<input type="button" value="blue" class="button-blue" />
<p id="result">This is an example</p>
```

Comment: Yes, I knew it wasn't that hard. Thanks!

Comment: @Divolka solution from mplungian is so much more elegant and generic you might want to look into it. It's actually much more generic than this solution, even though both works

Comment: I'll also try it

Comment: @Divolka This solution will not change the font size until you click a color.

Comment: @mplungjan I have updated the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [delegate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Here I have delegated the clicks and changes to a parent container. Then I have ONE function deciding what to do to the text

```js
const res = document.getElementById("result");
const style = document.getElementById("style")
const size = document.getElementById("size")
const changeIt = function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target; // whatever clicked or changed
  const fontSize = size.value; 
  result.style.fontStyle = style.value; // always
  result.style.fontSize = fontSize + "%"; // always
  if (tgt.classList.contains("color")) { // only when button is clicked
    result.style.color = tgt.id
  }
};

document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", changeIt)
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("input", changeIt)
```

```css
#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Text size
  <input type='number' id='size' min='50' class='input-width'>%
  </p>
  <p>
    <select id='style' size='2'>
      <option id='style-1'>normal</option>
      <option id='style-2'>italic</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>What color?</p>
  <input type='button' id='red' class='color' />
  <input type='button' id='green' class='color' />
  <input type='button' id='blue' class='color' />
  <p id='result'>This is an example</p>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad, indeed, I missed that part... I'll remove my comment :-)